# Gratis accountancy package that takes its input from a plain text file (or database; in fact, just not manual data entry)

Tags: gratis, accounting

A friend asked my search for this. Friend is UK based, if that makes any difference, accountancy wise.

Friend has a software application which someone else developed and which I am to take over.

Since the app allows pucrases and also funds transfer between users, it would be good to generate some accounts.  If not sufficient to submit officially, then at least 90% so, such that a profession accountant could quickly & effortlessly turn them into the real thing.

The only ***important*** requirement is that no one has to manually enter data since the app already has it. The idea is that the app (well, its server, actually) can export some data, which the accountancy app can process.

Preferably Windows, but Linux, Mac & self hosted web-based are also options.

I am thinking that the server can spit out a text file like:

> 8/9/22 10:23:15 Debit Alice Credit Bob Amount $5
> etc

Of course, that is just an idea. It could a real database (MySql, SQLite, Mongo, etc), or just a Comma Separated Variable text file, JSON, XML, you name it.

In fact, whatever the  input required by the accountancy program, I can arrange that the app's server produces data in that format.

And, not that I think about it, I just want an accountancy program whose save file format is not binary (and preferably has its format documented or easily reverse engineered). That was I can generate a save file that looks as if the data were input by and and saved, and can open that "generated save file" with the accountancy program. In which case, which is the best gratis program for UK accounting?

[Update] the program should be able to produce a profit & loss account and balance sheet.

Comment: Hi. Is this for personal accounting or for a company? May be also state the ones your friend has looked at already. This is one I came across recently that allows imports https://www.firefly-iii.org/.

Comment: I would be for a small UK Ltd company, which currently has no income to buy accountign packages

Comment: I followed your link & self-hosted looks goo. the data importer is a big bonus. Do you know if it can produce a profit & loss account and balance sheet? I need to update the question to state that those are required. If it can, please post an answer, which I will award. Thanks

Comment: If for business with profit & loss, balance sheet etc., an example is https://akaunting.com/ and here for code https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting . I believe it has imports for transactions. Firefly III is more for personal usage. I have not used either yet, but have been searching. Also see https://frontaccounting.com/ So all on my todo list...

Comment: It looks like Akounting runs only on their server (or did I miss something?). I am looking for desktop or self hosted.

Comment: FrontAccounting is self-hosted, though, and at first glance looks great (and probably more than I need, but that is not a problem). Now I juts need to look at the save file format

Comment: You can download code here https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting/releases . It's laravel/php based so I assume can run on XAMPP or LAMPP. Installation is listed towards end of page on https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting

Comment: Oh, thanks. I must have missed that. For my use case, I already posted to the FrontAccounting forum to ask if there is an HTTP API to allow me to add transactions, or if the save file format is documented/easily reverse engineered. I shall do the same for Akounting. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I forgot one more to check out... https://ledgersmb.org/

Comment: This also looks god. Please keep posting :-)

Comment: Note to self: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_accounting_software#Free_and_open_source_software  Also [Ledger](https://www.ledger-cli.org/) is entirely command line driven